# htmldoc error: unable to open files - looking in wrong path

Tags: centos, snap

I try to use htmldoc under CentOS Stream Release 9.

To install htmldoc I followed this site: https://snapcraft.io/install/htmldoc/centos
Mainly I did the following commands:

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install snapd
sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.socket
sudo ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap
sudo snap install htmldoc
```

This runs without any errors but when I afterwards try to use it like mentioned in the docs, I get a lot of errors.

```
htmldoc --webpage -f output.pdf http://www.duckduckgo.com
```

I get a real lot of error messages, all saying

```
ERR005: Unable to open psglyphs data file!
ERR005: Unable to open character set file iso-8859-1!
ERR005: Unable to open font width file /snap/htmldoc/759/share/htmldoc/fonts/Times-Roman.afm!
```

I had a look at the filesystem and found, that I have the mentioned file in
`/snap/htmldoc/759/usr/share/htmldoc/fonts` (because of the symlink its actually `/var/lib/snapd/snap/htmldoc/759/usr/share/htmldoc/fonts/`)
notice the additional usr-level in the directory structure.

So is there a way to fix this and make htmldoc find its files? Is it some kind of configuration or installation error? How to get rid of this?